# Auto update and build with eclipse and SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, build-process, performance, subclipse

every morning when i come to work i update my sources from the svn and build it. this process takes roughly 15 min.

my question is whether it is possible to do it automatically, scheduling it...

i am working with XP and eclipse.

Comment: Please specify what OS / platform you are on.

Comment: This is what Continuous Integration servers like Hudson do. https://hudson.dev.java.net/

Comment: Is this a Hudson plug in for eclipse?

Comment: [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org) and [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) are two _Continuous Integration_ build systems. Although each has an eclipse plugin, Hudson and Jenkins run on separate servers. They're pretty simple to install, and you could even install them on your system if you so desire. They're both very much alike, and were forked from the same project (There's a debate who forked who). I prefer Jenkins because Kohsuke Kawaguchi, the developer who wrote the original software, went with the Jenkins project.

Answer (score 3):

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247003/john) mentions in the comments, setting up an **[Hudson server](http://hudson-ci.org/)** is the quickest way to schedule this kind of task:

[image: Hudson Setup Job]